# Correct json to add a parent link to a TFS work item

Tags: json, powershell, tfs-workitem

I am trying to add a parent link to a TFS work item using powershell and json. We have an internal TFS server (ie, not team services).

I get answers to my queries, so my connection to TFS is working, but when I try to update I get the following error:

```
"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request."
```

I am a json noob and got my json skeleton from this [MSDN page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items)

Here is my json:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value":
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
        "url": "https://tfs.myCompany.org/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/259355",
        "attributes":
        {
            { "isLocked": false }
        }
    }
}
]
```

I tested with square brackets in a few places based on some other json samples I found but they didn't help so I returned to the syntax from the MSDN page above.

And this is the powershell script I am using.

```
param(
[System.String]$TaskId=288346
)

$username = "myUserInfo"
$password = "myPassword"

$securePassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $securePassword)       

$taskItemURL ="https://tfs.myCompanynet.org/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/$TaskId"
$taskItemRequest = $taskItemUrl+'?$expand=relations' 
$taskItemJson = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "$taskItemRequest" -Method get -
Credential $credential 

if($taskItemJson.relations)
{
    write-host "relation exists: " $taskItemJson.relations[0].url
}
else
{
   write-host "relation does not exist. Creating it."
   $jsonTemplate = Get-Content E:\scripts\JsonTemplate.txt # | ConvertTo-Json

   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $taskItemURL"?api-version=1.0" -Method patch -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json-patch+json -body $jsonTemplate
}
```

As you can see I have commented out the convertTo-json because I was getting this error:
    ConvertTo-Json : The converted JSON string is in bad format.
I wasn't sure if I was getting that error because it is already json.

I also tested skipping the get-content and using the -inFile parameter but it resulted in the same error above.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $taskItemURL"?api-version=1.0" -Method patch -Credential $credential -ContentType application/json-patch+json -InFile E:\scripts\JsonTemplate.txt
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with my json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aargh! I was so close. I chanced a guess that the double curly brackets under attribrutes were wrong even though [the documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) looks like it should be so. When I removed those it worked beautifully.

Now my json looks like this:

```
[
{
"op": "add",
"path": "/relations/-",
"value":
  {
    "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
    "url": "https://tfs.myCompany.org/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/259355",
    "attributes":
    {
         "isLocked": false 
    }
  }
}
]
```

Comment: Broken link above - you didn't ever have to update the parent value did you ? Struggling with this currently

Comment: Sorry to not answer earlier. Sigh, hard to keep track of MS's documentation moves.
I don't think I changed the parent. Did you get this to work?